# grouping categorical variables in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have a variable named 'Fever'  in which I have 4 options like mild, moderate, severe and very severe. I want to club moderate and mild together and severe and very severe together, how can I do it in 'R'?

Please suggest

Comment: You might want to have a look at the `recode` function from package `dplyr`. Or just generally how to create/change variables based on ifelse conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(fever = c("mild","moderate","severe","very severe"))
newdf <- mutate(df,highfever = case_when(fever == "mild" | fever == "moderate" ~ 0,
                                         fever == "severe" | fever == "very severe" ~ 1))
```

Comment: Thank you Schwarz. Sir I have it in a data set in which the column title is "Fever". If I take df$Fever - I am getting error.

Comment: in the mutate command you don't have to use the `$`. You simply use `df` before the comma and then `fever` in the mutate command

Comment: Awesome. If that solved your problem, I'd be grateful if you could accept the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

This type of vectors are normally factors.

```
library(forcats)
```

First create a vector of fevers

```
fever_lvl <- c("mild", "moderate", "severe", "very severe")
set.seed(1)
fevers <- factor(sample(fever_lvl, 10, T), levels = fever_lvl)

fevers
> fevers
 [1] mild        very severe severe      mild        moderate    mild        severe     
 [8] severe      moderate    moderate   
Levels: mild moderate severe very severe
```

Regrouping as desired

```
fevers_regrouped <- fct_recode(fevers, mild_or_moderate = "mild", mild_or_moderate = "moderate",
                               severe_or_higher = "severe", severe_or_higher = "very severe")

fevers_regrouped
> fevers_regrouped
 [1] mild_or_moderate severe_or_higher severe_or_higher mild_or_moderate mild_or_moderate
 [6] mild_or_moderate severe_or_higher severe_or_higher mild_or_moderate mild_or_moderate
Levels: mild_or_moderate severe_or_higher
```

or use `fct_collapse` as-

```
fevers_regrouped2 <- fct_collapse(fevers, mild_or_mod = c("mild", "moderate"),
                                  severe_or_up = c("severe", "very severe"))
fevers_regrouped2
 [1] mild_or_mod  severe_or_up severe_or_up mild_or_mod  mild_or_mod  mild_or_mod  severe_or_up severe_or_up
 [9] mild_or_mod  mild_or_mod 
Levels: mild_or_mod severe_or_up
```

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done using `base`:

```r
## If going from character to factor
fever_vec <- c("mild", "moderate", "severe", "very severe")
fever_fact <- factor(fever_vec,
                     levels = c("mild", "moderate", "severe", "very severe"),
                     labels = c("mild/moderate", "mild/moderate",
                                "severe/very severe", "severe/very severe"))

## If already going from a factor
fever_already_fact <- factor(c("mild", "moderate", "severe", "very severe"))
levels(fever_already_fact) <- list("mild/moderate" = c("mild", "moderate"),
                                   "severe/very severe" = c("severe", "very severe"))
```

Also, the 1st variant only works from R version >= 3.5.0.